# Lost access to a subdirectory in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions

I was deploying a web application using xcopy and somehow I lost access to a subdirectory of it.
I just tried to delete all subfolders and it failed, and from then I cannot read or write this directory.

- `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Webpage` works
- `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Webpage\Subdirectory` doesn't work.

If I click on the properties I miss the security tab.

It's an ASP.Net-MVC Application

It's also not possible to get ownership.

Comment: nobody can help?

Answer (score 0):

> It's also not possible to get ownership

Sure it is. You just have to log on as an administrator and follow [these easy steps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780020(WS.10).aspx). Make sure you do this on the top-level folder that you do have a security tab on.

Make sure that you tick the box to change the owner on all subfolders and objects. I'm assuming that's what you're missing. After that, you can add your account to the ACL for that directory with `Full Control` and then delete it at will.